# Python print out lastest value

Tags: python

i try to print("Hello World") and run it , it is fine, but when i change it to print("Hello") and print it , it cannot print out the 'Hello' and still print out Hello World, anyone can give me advise? thanks

Comment: Did you save the file?

Comment: Hi @Goion, yes i have save it

Comment: Well besides that there isn't much information to go about. Also, make sure you are running correct python file.

Comment: Can you show your code?? I know it's just `print("Hello World")` but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your file before running it again. You can do this with `ctrl+s` on windows for most text editors.

Comment: yes,i have save it